# If $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}\right) = 3$, does $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{f(h(h+2)) - f(0)}{h(h+2)}\right) = 3$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given that $f'(0) = 3$, I need to solve the limit: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\left(\frac{f(x^2 -1) - f(0)}{x^3 -1}\right)$$
Because $f'(0) = 3$, from first principles, I know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}\right) = 3$.
After some algebra, I arrive at

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\left(\frac{f(x^2 -1) - f(0)}{x^3 -1}\right) = \lim_{x\rightarrow1}\left(\frac{f((x-1)(x+1)) - f(0)}{(x-1)(x+1)}\right)\times\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\left(\frac{x+1}{x^2 + x + 1}\right)$$

Substitute $h = x-1$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\left(\frac{f(x^2 -1) - f(0)}{x^3 -1}\right)= \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{f(h(h+2)) - f(0)}{h(h+2)}\right)\times\frac{2}{3}$$

If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}\right) = 3$, does $\displaystyle\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{f(h(h+2)) - f(0)}{h(h+2)}\right) = 3$?

If so, the solution is $2$.

Comment: Just wondering how did you arrive at the term $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\left(\frac{x+1}{x^2 + x + 1}\right)$?

Comment: @YadatiKiran: Multiply top and bottom by $x+1$ after factoring $x^3-1$.

Comment: @Clayton :  But you have $x^2-1$ in the denominator not $x^3-1$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran: Factor $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. Now multiply top and bottom by $x+1$...

Comment: Actually, it just looks to me like you've edited the question incorrectly. You have $x^3-1$ in the denominator.

Comment: @Clayton you're right. I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=h(h+2)$ then $\frac{f(h(h+2))-f(0)}{h(h+2)}=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$.  Since $x\to 0$, as $h\to 0$, both ratios $\to 3$.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. Actually, if you know that $f'(0)=3$, it is true that 
$$
\lim\limits_{y\to a}\frac{f(j(y))-f(0)}{j(y)}=3
$$
if only $\lim\limits_{y\to a}j(y)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is substitution in limits:

> **Substitution Rule of Limits**: If $f(x) \to L$ as $x\to a$ and $g(x) \to a $ (but $g(x) \neq a$) as $x\to b$ then $f(g(x)) \to L$ as $x\to b$.

Rewrite your expression as $$\frac{f(x^2-1)-f(0)}{x^2-1}\cdot \frac{x^2-1}{x^3-1}$$ and note that the second fraction tends to $2/3$ as $x\to 1$. For the first fraction we use the rule of substitution and note that as $x\to 1$ we have $G(x) =x^2-1\to 0$ (and $G(x) \neq 0$) and as $x\to 0$ we have $F(x) =(f(x) - f(0))/x\to 3$ so that $F(G(x)) $ (the first fraction) tends to $3$ as $x\to 1$. Thus the desired limit is $3(2/3)=2$.